# How to replace dot with comma in price format in php

Tags: php, money-format

I have a price format like **1.100.000** Now I want to replace all dots with comma so it should look like this- **1,100,000**. To achieve this I tried this code-

```
<?php
$number=1.100.000;
$number=str_replace('.',',',$number);
?>
```

But it is not working. Can any one help.?

Comment: it should work anyways, but with string. if you write `$number=1.100.000;` you will get a syntax error

Comment: The code you posed is not valid - `1.100.000` is not a valid PHP float or integer.

Where does the value come from? Can you show a more complete representation of the code?

Comment: If you would had error reporting on you would never had to ask this question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Missing the quotes.Try this -

```
$number="1.100.000";
$number=str_replace('.',',',$number);
var_dump($number);
```

> OutPut -

```
string(9) "1,100,000"
```

Answer (score 4):

To make it a little bit more robust, you can only replace the dot only if it has 3 following numbers, so it does not replace cents. Try:

```
$number = "1.100.000.00";
$number = preg_replace('/\.(\d{3})/', ',$1', $number);
var_dump($number);
```

> OutPut -

```
string(12) "1,100,000.00"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use RegExp

`preg_replace('/\./', ',', $number);`

This would replace all '.' dots with ','.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is not working because

```
$number=1.100.000;  
var_dump($number);
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.000' (T_DNUMBER)

is not a string and `str_replace()` only works on `string` value

So you have to do this

```
$number="1.100.000";  (type = string)
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is **number_format()** function. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Follow this exemple:

```
$number = 1234.56;

// english notation (default)
$english_format_number = number_format($number);
// 1,235

// French notation with thousands separator
$nombre_format_francais = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
// 1 234,56

$number = 1234.5678;

// english notation without thousands separator
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
// 1234.57
```

Comment: the problem is that i don't want to put the decimal value... i don't want to round to 2 if the number has 3 decimals.